# Sharing XML instances following an XSD by reference

Tags: xml, xsd, uri, pass-by-reference

For a project where we want to share XML objects using a REST based service, we would like to share composed objects that consists of object with the types that we define. We want to be able to pass them by reference, using a URI.

Suppose I have following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com/custom"
    xmlns:custom="http://www.abc.com/custom">

<xsd:complexType name="collectionType">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="abc" type="xs:string"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence>
                 <xsd:element name="innerCollection" type="collectionType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Am I allowed to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Schema information -->
<custom:root>
   <custom:innerCollection ref="http://example.org/innerCollectionA" />
</custom:root>
```

Where "http://example.org/innerCollectionA" returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Schema information -->
<custom:innerCollection>
     <custom:abc>
          Inner Collection A
     </custom:abc>
</custom:innerCollection>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To share XML Schema definitions by reference**, use `xsd:import` if the definitions are in their own namespace (or `xsd:include` if in the same namespace):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com/custom"
            xmlns:custom="http://www.abc.com/custom"
            xmlns:collection="http://www.abc.com/collection">

  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.abc.com/collection" schemaLocation="collection.xsd"/>

  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="innerCollection" type="collection:collectionType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Note that `collection.xsd` can be any URI leading to a shared definition such as:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com/collection">

  <xsd:complexType name="collectionType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="abc" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

**To share XML instances between XML instances**, choose among the following approaches depending upon your requirements:

1. [XML Inclusions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/)
2. [XLink](http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink11/)
3. Use simple [xsd:anyURI](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#anyURI) attributes where you want to reference other
   XML instances.  Applications decide when/whether to de-reference.

Comment: OK Thanks, can you give an example where I include an XML instance of my innerCollection in custom:root that has the type collection:collectionType where I do not need to modify the XML schema of custom:root to allow anyURI/XLink/Include? I would like to have behavior like RDF (but with the advantage of a validating schema) where I can construct my xml objects based on URIs where an application can get de-reference the instance based on the URI.

Comment: Offhand, no, sorry, I do not know of any tools that would assist in validation across any of those inclusion mechanisms.  My recommendation would be to go the third route (let the applications decide when/whether to de-reference).  You can validate the parts separately or use XSLT to assemble and then validate the whole using standard validating parsers such as Xerces.